# Как посчитать сумму всех не пустых value

Tags: javascript

Есть input где выбираем возраст ребенка. Нужно записать в `class="input_quantity"` количество выбраных детей.

Сам код http://jsfiddle.net/upy6vz21/7/

```js
$('.quantity').click(function () {
  $('.children_box').toggleClass('open');
});
$('.children_input').click(function () {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open');
});
$('.children_box .option').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var value = text.replace(/[^-0-9]/gim,'');
  $(this).closest('.children-item').find('.input_val').val(value);
  $(this).closest('.children-item').find('.number_val').html(text);
  $('.children_age').removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
input[type="hidden"] {
    display: none;
}
.select {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.quantity {
    height: 45px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
.children_box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f2efef;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
.children_box.open {
  display: block;
}
.children_input {
  background-color: #d8d5e2;
  padding: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.children_age {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #d8d5e2;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.children_age.open {
  display: block;
}
.children_age li:hover {
  background-color: #f4f2f9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <div class="quantity">
    <span class="quantity_val">&mdash;</span>
    <input class="input_quantity" type="hidden"  value="">
  </div>
  <div class="children_box">
    <div class="children-item">
      <label class="children-title">
        Возраст 1 ребенка
      </label>
      <div class="children_input">
        <span class="number_val">&mdash;</span>
        <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
      </div>
      <ul class="children_age">
        <li class="option">1 год</li>
        <li class="option">2 года</li>
        <li class="option">3 года</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="children-item">
      <label class="children-title">
        Возраст 2 ебенка
      </label>
      <div class="children_input">
        <span class="number_val">&mdash;</span>
        <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
      </div>
      <ul class="children_age">
        <li class="option">1 год</li>
        <li class="option">2 года</li>
        <li class="option">3 года</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Когда мы вибираем возраст ребенка его возраст записывается в class="input_val". Мне нужно посчитать количество дитей у которых указан возраст. И вывести это значение в class="input_quantity"

Comment: Что у вас не получается сделать самостоятельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переберите все инпуты.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rusic/3qnr7xdj/2/

```js
$('.quantity').click(function() {
  $('.children_box').toggleClass('open');
});
$('.children_input').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open');
});
$('.children_box .option').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var value = text.replace(/[^-0-9]/gim, '');
  $(this).closest('.children-item').find('.input_val').val(value);
  $(this).closest('.children-item').find('.number_val').html(text);
  $('.children_age').removeClass('open');

  var sum = 0;
  $('.input_val').each(function() {
    sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt($(this).val());
  })
  $('.quantity_val').text(sum);
  $('.input_quantity').val(sum);

});
```

```css
input[type="hidden"] {
  display: none;
}

.select {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.quantity {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.children_box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f2efef;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.children_box.open {
  display: block;
}

.children_input {
  background-color: #d8d5e2;
  padding: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.children_age {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #d8d5e2;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.children_age.open {
  display: block;
}

.children_age li:hover {
  background-color: #f4f2f9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <div class="quantity">
    <span class="quantity_val">&mdash;</span>
    <input class="input_quantity" type="hidden" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="children_box">
    <div class="children-item">
      <label class="children-title">
        Возраст 1 ребенка
      </label>
      <div class="children_input">
        <span class="number_val">&mdash;</span>
        <input class="input_val" type="hidden" value="0">
      </div>
      <ul class="children_age">
        <li class="option">1 год</li>
        <li class="option">2 года</li>
        <li class="option">3 года</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="children-item">
      <label class="children-title">
        Возраст 2 ебенка
      </label>
      <div class="children_input">
        <span class="number_val">&mdash;</span>
        <input class="input_val" type="hidden" value="0">
      </div>
      <ul class="children_age">
        <li class="option">1 год</li>
        <li class="option">2 года</li>
        <li class="option">3 года</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: нужна не сумма а количество детей у которых заполнили значение value

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rusic/tabvus3f/

Answer (score 0):

Начните с увеличения версии jQuery до той, где есть `closest`.

---

```
function updateChildCount(el) {
  var count = 0;
  $(el).closest(".children_box").find(".input_val").each(function(){
    if (this.value != "")
      count++;
  });
  $(el).closest(".select").find(".input_quantity").val(count);
}

$('.children_box .option').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var value = text.replace(/[^-0-9]/gim,'');
  $(this).closest('.children-item').find('.input_val').val(value);
  $(this).closest('.children-item').find('.number_val').html(text);
  $('.children_age').removeClass('open');

  updateChildCount(this);
});
```